# Why does it seem as if my static constructor is only executed once?

Tags: c#, static, static-members

When I have a `static` field in my class:

```
public static int Counter = 0;
```

With a `static` constructor:

```
static Class() { 
    Counter++; 
}
```

When I create an object of this class and check `Class.Counter` it shows me `1` which is correct.

But when I create another object of the same class, `Class.Counter` remains `1`.

Why is that?

Comment: MSDN should be your first choice , not stackoverflow.

Comment: If you're going down this route make sure you think about multithreading. There are a couple of thread safe alternatives which will save you problems in the long run

Comment: from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx - A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Comment: Btw, if you're planning to have a global instance counter (why, btw?), you should use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The most ultimate of facepalms I give unto you.

Comment: Sorry for using SO, it's just newbie mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because the static constructor is executed only once.

From [C# Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The static constructor for a class executes at most once in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain:
>
> - An instance of the class is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class are referenced.

Comment: Why does the static constructor executed only once? -> Because the static constructor is executed only once. Great answer. :)

Comment: @PavelRyzhov the title has been changed :-)

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are incrementing your counter in static constructor, and it will be executed just once.

[static constructor C# - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs to be **performed once only**.
>   It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

You can fix it by incrementing in instance constructor like:

```
class Class
{
    public static int counter = 0;

    public Class()
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

For thread-safety use `Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);` instead of `counter++`

Comment: @Liath, yes in that case `Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);` could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Selman22 has it correct, here is a little more detail:

From MSDN

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. 
>   It is called automatically before the first instance is >created or any static members are referenced.

Static constructors have the following properties:

- A static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters.
- A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.
- A static constructor cannot be called directly.
- The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in
  the program.
- A typical use of static constructors is when the class is using a log
  file and the constructor is used to write entries to this file.
- Static constructors are also useful when creating wrapper classes for
  unmanaged code, when the constructor can call the LoadLibrary method.

If a static constructor throws an exception, the runtime will not invoke it a second time, and the type will remain uninitialized for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program is running.

Reference url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx